# Default font size with postscript device

Tags: r, plot, postscript

I am generating eps figures in R using the postscript device, something like this (simplified):

```
require(extrafont)
#font_import() # I did it only once when installing new fonts
# see http://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2013/09/09/preparing-figures-for-plos-one-with-r/
loadfonts(device = "postscript")
postscript("elev.eps", width = 70/25.4, height = 75/25.4,
           family = "Myriad Web Pro", paper = "special", onefile = FALSE,
           horizontal = FALSE)
barplot(krk$counts, space=0, horiz=T, cex.axis = 0.7)
dev.off()
```

Now my question is about the font size I am trying to fiddle with using `cex.axis`, in a clumsy way. I am supposed to have the axis labels in font size 8. Can I somehow tell the postscript device that I want the base font size = 8? I.e. for cex = 1 I want font size = 8. All I found available is the `cex` parameter, which is relative to *something* which I don't know how to even get, let alone set...

PS: I tried `?postscript` but haven't found the answer

Comment: You set the point size when you instantiate the font, either with the scalefont or setfont operator. I have no idea how you would persuade R to produce the output you want, presumably it must be producing PostScript containing one of those operators or everything would be in the default font (Courier usually)

Comment: Please try reading `?postscript` again.

Comment: @BondedDust couldn't you just point out the key part?

Comment: The comment by KenS suggested that you seek to modify the "point size". Since there is a `pointsize` parameter listed in Courier font along the left side of the Arguments list, I thought surely that was enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This produced the expected dimunition in font size on my device.

```
postscript("elev.eps", width = 70/25.4, height = 75/25.4,
            paper = "special", onefile = FALSE,
           horizontal = FALSE, pointsize=8)
barplot(1,1, space=0, horiz=T, cex.axis = 0.7)
dev.off()
```

[image]

(That image is rotated 90 degrees from how it displays in my pdf-viewer, but I don't think your issue relates to the horizontal argument.)

Comment: Thanks BondedDust. I have seen this parameter in `?postscript` but seems rather confusing: *"pointsize: 
the default point size to be used. Strictly speaking, in bp, that is 1/72 of an inch, but approximately in points. Defaults to 12."* What? Pointsize is given, isn't it? Point size is given, fixed, it is 1/72 inch. How can you change it? I would expect something like changing *font size [in points]*, not chaning point size! This is confusing.

Comment: I suppose you could see it was confusing. I took that to mean the the dimensions of a point was fixed but the 'pointsize' was the number of points for the text font. Maybe it's easier for those of us who know little about the arcane art of typography than for those of you who are better versed in it?

Comment: The unit a 'point' is a fixed size, 1/72 of an inch, the 'point size' of a font is the size of a font, the units are points, hence 'point size'. Its very normal usage i typography publishing.

Comment: I do understand your "points". I hope you understand mine. I think I did answer the question, even if you still have concerns for the wording of the help page. If you want it changed, the proper approach is to submit a 'diff' file to the "R Core" at the r-devel Mailing List. (I'm not in R Core, so even if I accept your explanation it has no lasting effect.)

Comment: Thank you both guys for your replies! I also found `par(ps = 8)`, which is probably better because it affects font size only (not the pch size).